# Count rows which meet criteria, ignoring rows with same non-unique value (I.E all awards before a certain date in a unique country)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, unique, google-sheets-formula

Below is the sheet template I am working on.

[image: Sheet to find function for]

and here is a link to a copy of it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qfbDihg0q3XTWCEdHUwT7RLjTerIeK0z-JLuihkmTp4/edit?usp=sharing

I would like to be able to count each row that meets a set of criteria, for example I would like to know each row that received an award in a unique country after 2015

I have tried a formula like this (subRec is the name of the sheet shown above):

```
=COUNTIFS(Arrayformula(IF(subRec!E2:E=FALSE,FALSE,true)),True,ARRAYFORMULA(IF(subRec!C2:C<DATE(2015,1,1),False,True)),true,ARRAYFORMULA(if((COUNTIF(subRec!F2:F,subRec!F2:F))>1,False,True)),true)
```

However, this results in a reduction in the count if I were to add another row which had a non-unique country, since it filters out ALL non-uniques rather than counting only the first successful one.

Ideally, the formula should:

1. check each row against an arbitrary number of criteria and count that row if it meets all of them
2. where there are uniques for columns like Country or Salon, find the first row which meets all criteria, add it to the count and ignore the rest that have that same non-unique value

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: @player0 added the link

Comment: examples of output i want can be found on the portrec sheet, formulas i have tried can also be found there

Comment: so you need formula for **portRec!M2** is that right? and by "unique" you mean only those rows that as 1st meet given criteria not those rows that have non repeating countries in whole set, right?

Comment: yes, though a formula structure that could also be used for L2, J2, I2, H2 and G2 would be preferred, they have a very similar logical structure

Comment: I think you have it, to clarify i need the number of, say, Awards that have been given in a unique country.  So if i got 5 awards, 2 from Scotland and 2 from Ireland and 1 from England, it should count up to 3, as i have an award for each country and there are 3 unique countries

Comment: answer updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER(subRec!F2:F, 
 subRec!E2:E=TRUE, 
 subRec!C2:C>DATE(2015, 1, 1)))))
```

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

Comment: thanks this appears to give the results i want.  Could you walk through your answer and explain it further so I don't make a mistake replicating this in the future?

Comment: sure, we need to count country so that's column F so we put it in FILTER with two criteria (if E is true and C is past 2015) so every time the two criteria meet FILTER will output the value of corresponding row eg. F. then we just enclose it with UNIQUE to get the list of unique values. then we use IFERROR just in case there will be no unique value then it will output N/A and COUNTA would count it as 1 instead of 0

Comment: that makes a lot of sense.  Thanks again you ended an evening of headaches trying to get this to work!  Accepted as answer